# ¿Como validar si un parametro es un numero entero en UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix, validación

Tengo que hacer un script que reciba dos parámetros, de los cuales el segundo debe ser un número entero. No tengo idea de como validar eso.

```
 if test $2 =~ "^[0-9]+$"
 then
  echo "\nNumero positivo entero"
 else
  echo "\nError: El numero $2 no es un numero entero positivo!!!\a"
 fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu puedes usar expresiones regulares para validar numeros, ya sean enteros, enteros negativos o decimales, tu podrías realizar algo como esto:

```
validate_number=^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$;
echo "Please Enter your number ";
read number
if ![[ $number =~ $validate_number ]]; then
echo "number not valid"
fi
```

las expresiones reguales son:

[1.] ^-? esta expresión verifica el principio de cadena y si contiene algún caracter solo uno -

[2.] [0-9]  verifica que sean numeros del 0 al 9

[3.] el caracter + especifica el operador o

[4.] ([.][0-9]+)$ confirma si el valor ingresado fue un número decimal y verifica el final de cadena con $

El código anterior recibe un argumento de teclado y verifica si lo ingresado fue realmente un numero, ya sea positivo, negativo o decimal

Comment: Me gusto que explicaras que onda con cada cosa, por que la verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo y asi ya se mas que solo escribir por escribir. (:

Answer (score 0):

Se puede validar con un `case`:

```
case $2 in
(""|*[^0-9]*) printf "\nError: ¡¡¡ [$2] no es un número entero positivo !!!\007\n";;
(*) printf "\nNúmero entero positivo\n";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un método que reciba parámetros, que tome el valor del segundo y valide si es Entero o no, por ejemplo:

```
esEnteroSegundoParametro() {

    echo "Valor parametro #1 is $1"
    echo "Valor parametro #2 is $2"

    #Revisa si el segundo parámetro es un entero.
    if echo "$2" | egrep -q '^\-?[0-9]+$'; then 
       echo "$2 es un entero."
    else 
       echo "$2 NO es un entero."
    fi
}
```

Si ejecutamos el método con los siguientes valores:

```
esEnteroSegundoParametro 14 12.2
```

obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecutamos el método con los siguientes valores:

```
esEnteroSegundoParametro 14 12
```

obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es filtrarlo por control de error viendo que si es un digito y si es mayor que 0 es un numero entero sino, pues no.

```
echo -en $caracter | grep '[[:digit:]]' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 && $caracter -gl 0 ]
then
    echo "Es un digito entero"

# Si no, mostrem un missatge indicant que no és ni lletra ni nombre
else
    echo "No es un digito entero"
fi
```